# Solution for LockAcquisitionException in hibernate with EJB

Tags: java, multithreading, hibernate, ejb

I am using EJB and hibernate in my application. In certain scenario I am supposed to have a native SQL query like this `UPDATE MY_TABLE SET VALUE = VALUE + 1 WHERE MY_KEY=20;` (Along with this query within the same transaction there is also some other hibernate operation is available, but those are not operation in the same table). And the same query will have a chance to run in another transaction, which means a separate thread will try to run the same UPDATE query along with some other hibernate operations. When single thread is in action then every thing is fine but in multiple thread scenario I am getting the following exception

```
org.hibernate.exception.LockAcquisitionException: could not execute native bulk manipulation query
at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:105)
at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.NativeSQLQueryPlan.performExecuteUpdate(NativeSQLQueryPlan.java:198)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.executeNativeUpdate(SessionImpl.java:1191)
at org.hibernate.impl.SQLQueryImpl.executeUpdate(SQLQueryImpl.java:357)
at x.y.z.myMethod(MyClass.java:154)
```

I cannot have a situation to reduce the thread to 1. I am having Isolation level of `READ_UNCOMMITTED`. Why I am getting this exception? What is happening in a thread race? Any solution? How to fix?

Comment: Hi I am getting same exception and in the same scenario. Did you find any solution. Any other alternative